# Dir command listing to show folder and file count, and directory size (no list)

Tags: cmd.exe, dir

I'm trying to get a basic count of a directory, but I do not want the result to list the names of the files contained in there. Basically, what I want would be the same as a Windows properties listing, but I can't use this because some of the file paths are too long, and these are being omitted from the count.

So, I ultimately want a window showing the path that the count was taken from, the number of files and folders, and the overall size of the directory.  I'm assuming a dir command would be the handiest way to do this, but I'm not sure of the correct switches to use.

Thanks!

Comment: [relevant](http://serverfault.com/questions/110725/windows-command-prompt-how-to-get-the-count-of-all-files-in-current-directory)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo %cd% & dir | findstr /b /c:"  "
```

Show current directory and filter the output of the dir command to only show the required information